# Spring Boot WebSockets unable to find the current user (principal)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-websocket

After signing-in, the websockets cannot find the current user by `session.getPrincipal()` (it returns null).

Here is the Java code for WebSockets:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/socket");
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/app").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

It seems like a Spring Boot bug - I am using `1.3.8 RELEASE`.  After refreshing the page, it gets the logged-in user properly.

And here is the front-end (subscription)

```
ngstomp.subscribeTo('/user/queue/message')
.callback(function(response) {
    console.log('Test');
})
.withBodyInJson()
.connect();
```

I tried this solution: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/11/spring-boot-based-websocket-application-and-capturing-http-session-id.html

But it's not working.

Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you required to have session.getPricncipal(). Spring provides Principal object to be injected automatically in your controller as following.

```
@MessageMapping("/message")
public String processMessageFromClient(@Payload String message, Principal principal) throws Exception {
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(),    "/queue/reply", name);
        return name;
    }
```

Reference: [Spring Boot Websocket Example](http://www.devglan.com/faq/spring-boot-websocket-integration-example)

Comment: It seems before-sign-in's session ID is different than after-sign-in's session ID.

Comment: I am using an annotation: `@SendToUser`

Comment: `@MessageMapping("/message")
    @SendToUser
    public String loadMessage(@Payload String message) {
     return message;
    }`

Comment: In the server side you requires to have  @SendToUser("/queue/message"), then client can expect messages at /user/queue/message

Comment: Would it be possible to get it via some utility class instead of the method?