# Spring boot websocket: how to get the current principal programmatically?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket

By this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42048024/spring-boot-websockets-unable-to-find-the-current-user-principal/42187176) I know that I can access to the principal by passing it as an argument to the method.

Nevetheless I need to access to this information in a transparent way, I tried with:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

But it gives me null. So, isn't there another way?

It seems that, in order to obtain the full reference I have to define a custom channel interceptor:

```
 private static class MyReceiver implements ChannelInterceptor{
    

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        SimpMessageType type = getType(message);
        if(type == SimpMessageType.SUBSCRIBE) {
            message.getHeaders().get("simpUser")); //it works here
        }
        return ChannelInterceptor.super.preSend(message, channel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
  String username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
} else {
  String username = principal.toString();
}
```

This will give you the current logged-in Username in `Spring Security`

Note :

1. `UserDetails` object is the one that Spring Security uses to keep user-related information.
2. `SecurityContext` is used to store the details of the currently authenticated user and `SecurityContextHolder` is a helper class that provides access to the security context

Comment: I know, but for websockets I get null pointer exception...

Comment: Do you have : `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/user");` added to your spring security configuration `configure(WebSecurity web)` function ? If yes, Please remove that line and try once.

Comment: Same....the only way I found is to get the principal inside of a channel interceptor :(